# How does Mouse click raises a Button's event

Tags: c#, wpf, events

There are two pieces of code here 1st WPF and the 2nd one is a console Application

```
// This is a default Form1 class of a WPF application
// and I have added a button to the form.
partial class Form1
{
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(62, 12);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "Lloyd";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
} 

// here the buttons on the form are declared private
// how does the mouse click access the private button's event 
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
```

This is a console Application. 
I got the confusion while experimenting with this program.
Here the PublishingBall class is analogous the Button class,
this class has an event Throw which is analogous to Click event.
In the main method I am trying to replicate a mouse click
by selecting some numbers which will call the PublishingBall's events
but I could only access the PublishingBall events because they are publicly defined in the FielderSubscriber's class
however in previous code the button object is privately defined in Form1 class.
So how does the mouse click access button's events!

```
namespace PublisherAndSubscriber2ndNameSpace
{
class PublisherSubscriberPattern
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("want to throw the ball");
        int decision = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        PublisherBall puball = new PublisherBall();

        FielderSubscriber fielder = new FielderSubscriber(puball);

        // this is like the basic way to raise events, how i learnt it.
        // but i wanted to know how the mouse click raises button's event
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(decision))
        {
            puball.OnThrowEvent(new BallEventArgs() { Speed = 1001 });
        }


        Console.WriteLine("throw a ball");
        int selectBall;
        while (!Console.ReadKey().Equals(ConsoleKey.Escape))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a ball to throw 1 2 3 4");
            selectBall = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // trying to simulate a mouse click by using keyboard key value
            // Here I can only access PublishingBall objets because they are defined public in FielderSubscriber class
            switch (selectBall)
            {
                case 1: fielder.pace.OnThrowEvent(new BallEventArgs() { Speed = 162 });
                    break;
                case 2: fielder.spin.OnThrowEvent(new BallEventArgs() { Speed = 90 });
                    break;
                case 3: fielder.googly.OnThrowEvent(new BallEventArgs() { Speed = 50 });
                    break;
                case 4: fielder.bouncer.OnThrowEvent(new BallEventArgs() { Speed = 150 });
                    break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("enter between 1 to 4");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Custom eventArgs defined for the PublisherBall 
class BallEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}

// This class is analogous to a button class
class PublisherBall
{
    public event EventHandler<BallEventArgs> Throw = delegate { };

    public void OnThrowEvent(BallEventArgs e)
    {
        Throw(this, e);
    }
}

// This class is analogous to the Form1 class where i would Instantiate the button objects(private)
class FielderSubscriber
{
    public PublisherBall pace;
    public PublisherBall spin;
    public PublisherBall googly;
    public PublisherBall bouncer;

    // one way is to send the PublisherBall's object to the constructor
    public FielderSubscriber(PublisherBall ball)
    {
        ball.Throw += ball_Throw;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void InitializeComponent()
    {
        pace = new PublisherBall();
        pace.Throw += pace_Throw;

        spin = new PublisherBall();
        spin.Throw += spin_Throw;

        googly = new PublisherBall();
        googly.Throw += googly_Throw;

        bouncer = new PublisherBall();
        bouncer.Throw += bouncer_Throw;
    }

    void bouncer_Throw(object sender, BallEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A bouncer @{0}kmph", e.Speed);
    }

    void googly_Throw(object sender, BallEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A googly @{0}kmph", e.Speed);
    }

    void spin_Throw(object sender, BallEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A spin @{0}kmph", e.Speed);
    }

    void pace_Throw(object sender, BallEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A pace @{0}kmph", e.Speed);
    }

    // An Event Handler method
    void ball_Throw(object sender, BallEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Speed > 100)
            Console.WriteLine("wew tough catch {0}kmph", e.Speed);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("easy catch {0}kmph");
    }
}
}
//P.S I am a total noob , please be gentle
```

Comment: 1st example is Windows Forms not WPF

Comment: Ahh my bad , you are correct

Comment: @Marcin Iwanowski As a side question, is this a correct way to create and raise events or are there better ways to do it , w.r.t Publisher and subscriber pattern?

Comment: I noticed only that in your FielderSubscriber class you never detach from the event. It doesn't matter in this particular program but if you use it in another code then fielder object will not be collected by GC until PublisherBall object is live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Button works in the Windows Forms is much more complicated. As you can see using the Reflector or a similar tool the Button class inherit from the ButtonBase and there is protected WndProc method that accepts messages. If a message contains "click" code then this method raises the Click event. In simple words, every control that is added to visual tree (is displayed) receives messages from Window loop whatever happens on that specific window. If a control decides that message is important then it raises appropriate event.